# Check if an URL variable begins with a special domain name

Tags: php

Is it possible check and compare if `$url` begins with a special domain name that I specify?

```
<?
    $url = 'http://someurl';
    if /* $url begins with http://my.url.com */ {
        echo 'yes';
    }
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://someurl';
if (preg_match('@^http://searching\.url@', $url)) {
    echo 'it is url';
}
```

there's many ways to do this, first argument of `preg_match` is string you're searching for, in this case it's regex

```
<?php
$url = 'http://someurl';
if (strpos($url, 'http://searching.url') === 0) {
    echo 'it is url';
}
```

this way you are checking if searching string is on first position in other string (index 0)